# Delete automatic DB snapshot in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to delete an automatic DB snapshot.

I have a bunch of snapshots created when I delete stacks by the [BackupRetentionPeriod](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-backuprententionperiod) property, and now deleting a stack fails with `CREATE_FAILED` for `AWS::RDS::DBClusterSnapshot` - `Cannot create more than 100 manual snapshots`.

So I need to cleanup some snapshots, but the Delete Snapshot option is greyed out:

[image]

Also, why does it say "manual snapshots" in the error when they are automatically created on stack deletion?

Answer (score 5):

My understanding (based on trial-and-error only) is that Automated snapshots, can only be deleted by reducing the retention period. Then wait for the next Automated backup-cycle to run (usually once/day).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html#USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.BackupRetention

Comment: You can't reduce the retention to 0 if you're on a cluster though. Just FYI

Answer (score 1):

You may not delete automatic snapshots either from the console or via API/AWS CLI. Furthermore if you have a cluster you may also not reduce the retention period to 0.

The one way to delete automatic backups is to delete the instance/cluster itself:

> Automated backups are deleted when the DB instance is deleted. Only manually created DB Snapshots are retained after the DB Instance is deleted.

(from https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#24)